# Bitrix: Extended export in XML

Tags: php, bitrix

How can I export an iblock to .xml, but with my specific tags? Or how can I directly generate a sitemap .xml? (But I don't want that the sitemap contains only the links, I need the name, date, description.. etc.)

Comment: Create your custom export file and run it

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the information block to .XML and generating a sitemap.xml are completely different issues.

Customizing RSS output is very easy. Create a PHP page with the following code:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list","your-template-name",Array(
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => <YOUR-IBLOCK-TYPE>,
    "IBLOCK_ID" => <YOUR-IBLOCK-ID>,
.... other options of the "bitrix:news.list"
    )
);?>
```

copy the default iblock template to "your-template-name" and modify the PHP file in the template that outputs RSS.

Then call your PHP page with ?rss=Y parameter.

As about the custom sitemap, there is no easy way to customize it.

But you can edit \bitrix\modules\search\classes\general\sitemap.php

Looks for the tags like urlset there and modify the PHP file accordingly. Please be aware that on next Bitrix CMS updates, you changes will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I export an iblock to .xml, but with my specific tags?

There are several options:

1. Through api get the data and generate the output. If edition "Small
   business" or "Business" you can take one of the standard export for
   example.
2. Use news.list or catalog.section.
3. Customize rss.out